# What is the syntax to add a constraint on an already-created table?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, documentation

PostgreSQL *exclusion constraints* are documented briefly under

- [DDL-Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)
- [CREATE TABLE .. CONSTRAINT .. EXCLUDE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) *As linked in ddl-constraint*

But, the syntax for [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) does not mention /EXCLUDE/ anywhere. How do I add one if one is not already present.

I can in psql, TAB-complete

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD
```

However subsequent tabs do not provide `CONSTRAINT` which the documentation mentions nor anything that comes after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the example here by [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41706918/124486)

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT only_one_is_active_value_per_name
    EXCLUDE  USING gist
    ( name WITH =, 
      is_active WITH <> 
    );
```

**The `ALTER TABLE` command only lists *examples* of constraints. Constraints are actually added with the same syntax on [`DDL-Constraints`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html),**

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  -- stuff
  EXCLUDE USING gist ( name WITH =, is_active WITH <> );
);

ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT
  EXCLUDE USING gist ( name WITH =, is_active WITH <> );
```